# US C1 transit visa supporting document

Tags: usa, transit, transit-visas

If I'm transiting via the USA to Guatemala and because I'm allowed to enter Guatemala on basis of a US visa (as mentioned on embassy website of Guatemala), do I need to have visa for Guatemala to submit as a supporting document for US C1 transit visa?

MY PURPOSE: Travel to Guatemala from INDIA for business purpose(client)
CIRCUMSTANCE: There are no direct flights from INDIA to GUATEMALA, so have to travel via US to access connecting flight
SOLUTION ANTICIPATED: To travel via US transit, need to have a C1 transit visa
GUATEMALA ENTRY REQUIREMENTS: According to embassy websites(official): Indian citizens are allowed to have entry in GUATEMALA if they hold valid US visa on passport
PROBLEM1: If US visa officers will consider this scenario when a person in transit do not have a visa of destination country(Guatemala) (MY question)

END RESULT: US VISA OFFICERS rejected the visa request and they are pretty straightforward to refuse visas if there are discerning scenarios ::(())

Comment: A _transit_ visa is usually not sufficient for such a visa exemption.

Comment: If you already have a US visa, you do not need a transit visa. If you are getting a transit visa, this visa is not sufficient for exception for Guatemala; so you need a visa for Guatemala.

Comment: I don't understand. You say that you can get into Guatemala using your US visa. So why can't you get into _the USA_ using your US visa? Voting to close as unclear since the question is either based ona misunderstanding or needs to be edited to clarify what the actual situation is.

Comment: @DavidRicherby the way I read the Q (and given the helpful comment of BurhanKhalid), the OP does not have any visa yet and is (likely wrongly) assuming that they could use a US transit visa for entry to Guatemala and now is asking what documents (Guatemala visa) they need to apply for the US visa. That is answerable and I have voted to leave open, even though I agree that an edit to clarify would help a lot!

Comment: @mts Oh. If _that's_ what the question is and it's edited to say that, then I'll retract my close vote, or vote to reopen.

Comment: Note you can fly via Panama City-Tocumen or Mexico City into Guatemala. Both of those have flights from quite a few major European connection points (London, Paris, Amsterdam, Frankfurt) which in turn have direct flights from Delhi.

Comment: Those are viable options, but: 1. We don't know if the OP is travelling from Delhi and 2. that doesn't address the issue expressed by the OP.

Comment: Sure. Just in case the OP wants to avoid the hassle of getting a USA visa. And AFAIK Indian citizens can transit in the Netherlands without a transit visa so OP can do it without a Schengen visa, too. For an ... interesting ... option you can even do Delhi-Tokyo Narita-Mexico City-Guatemala. I just used Delhi as a major starting point.

Comment: Also @venkatesh mundada, why don't you simply get a C1 U.S. transit visa in addition to a Guatemalan visa? That way, your C1 visa has a destination, so that the American officials don't wonder why you have no visa for your destination country. I realized you just got it refused, but maybe if you reapply with a Guatemalan visa, they'll see your reasoning. Also, I don't see the harm in getting a Guatemalan visa (even if you don't theoretically need it).

Comment: @chx, thanks for the alternative options...i even thought for option of india-copenhagen-Guatemala, But as I suggested by travel consultants, a schenegan visa might have been possibly required for transit and as I never traveled Europe before, I was bound to get the single entry Schengen visa which only drops me to Guatemala and hinder my return to my home India. Hence I risked and hounded for US visa into forlorn attempts.

Answer (score 5):

In your situation, there is no good reason to get a C1 transit visa.  Many U.S. Embassies and Consulates issue B1/B2 visas to C1 applicants as a matter of course, and hold C1 applicants to the same level of scrutiny they would normal B1/B2 applicants.  Furthermore, C1 visas have the same validity as B1/B2 visas, and they both cost $160.

The simplest solution for you would be to apply for a B1/B2 tourist visa, explain to the officer that your itinerary actually calls for you to travel to Guatemala, and mention that Guatemala allows entry to foreign nationals with U.S. visas.

An approved Guatemalan visa is not a very meaningful support document, as Guatemala is not known for their rigorous visa screening.  After all, they let people in with another country's visa.

Answer (score 3):

To obtain a US C1 transit visa; you need to provide proof of transit. This is usually in the form of a travel itinerary and it has to be reasonably expeditious. This means, it cannot be a very long layover.

The exact text from the US Department of State [travel.state.gov](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/other/transit.html) (with my emphasis):

> Transit (C) visas are nonimmigrant visas for persons traveling in
>   immediate and continuous transit through the United States en route to
>   another country, with few exceptions. Immediate and continuous transit
>   is defined as **a reasonably expeditious departure of the traveler in
>   the normal course of travel as the elements permit and assumes a
>   prearranged itinerary without any unreasonable layover privileges.** If
>   the traveler seeks layover privileges for purposes other than for
>   transit through the United States, such as to visit friends or engage
>   in sightseeing, the traveler will have to qualify for the type of visa
>   required for that purpose.

Now, this visa is a temporary non-immigration visa for the purposes of transit. It does not provide any other benefits for you (such as repatriation to the US); and more importantly - is not valid for visa free access to Guatemala.

As far as Guatemala is concerned; you need to obtain an normal visa. See [this page](http://www.minex.gob.gt/Visor_Pagina.aspx?PaginaID=21) for your nationality to see if you require a visa, and what are the exceptions for your citizenship(s).

Comment: According to above link you provided, for Indians, the need of normal Guatemalan visa isn't required. I showed the above website as a supporting document in my visa appointment for C1 US transit today & it got refused.

Comment: THE US VISA GUYS EXPECT STRAIGHTFORWARD VIGILANT REASONS for the approval. They expected me to have a Guatemala visa(destination country visa) on my passport. May be THESE US guys might have felt the misuse of US c1 visa happening for the hassle free entry to some unknown country.lesson learnt: NEVER DISCERN WITH THE PURPOSE.....I'm depressed...and yeah i deserve to say these visa guys are IMPETUOUS too XX))

Comment: It says right there on the website: _"From June 6th of 2011, **all nationals of India carriers of ordinary passport who wish to travel to Guatemala should make their visa application at a US Embassy or Consulate of Guatemala abroad.** It should be noted that those Hindus national who have a valid visa to the United States, Canada or Schengen they do not need a visa to enter Guatemalan territory. "_ - so its clear you needed to apply for a visa first.

Comment: @Venkatesh Mundada, While Guatemala allows entry with a U.S. visa, that does not include a C1 transit visa.  If your plan was to get *only* a C1 transit visa and use that for entry into Guatemala, it would not have worked.  You need either a B1/B2 visa, or a C1 visa and a Guatemelan visa.  If you applied for only a C1 visa, that is the reason you were refused.